# How to get full user name in the output of 'top' command in *nix?

Tags: python, unix

I need to extract process details from top command on a few *nix systems I monitor. The details needed are username, command executed, PID, PPID, username and resident memory consumption.

If memory usage is greater than a threshold or command is illegal, I need to send a warning to the user at **username@company.com**

I am writing a script to do this in python and get the required data by executing 'top -bc -n 1' and grepping for command keyword. However, I also need to extract username for the illegal processes to send the mail warning.

However, top automatically truncates usernames greater than 8 characters. How do I retrieve the full user names?

Comment: What about matching it with `/etc/password`? `grep ^user /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1`

Comment: I thought of this earlier but when I looked into the /etc/passwd file, I couldn't find any of the user names there. The system I am working on is part of an enterprise computational cluster and I'm not sure how it is configured to authenticate logins if not for /etc/passwd. All I have at my disposal is the standard unix toolset.

Comment: @fedorqui what if there are several matches?

Comment: @Mindstorm right, direct access to `/etc/passwd` is always wrong, the proper way is `getent passwd`

Comment: Ok, @Mindstorm, in this case it is not worth doing what I said.

Comment: @wRAR. I also thought about several matches, and you are right. It was just an approach and you just discovered me `getent passwd`. Good to know it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the user id, then parse it to get the username:

```
getent passwd | grep <UID> | awk -F: '{ print $1; }'
```

That, and as @wRAR says, use `ps` instead of `top`.

Comment: again, this implies there is only one matching username

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `ps` instead of `top` as I don't know any reasons why `top` would be better for this task. You can configure `ps` output much more flexibly than `top` one.

Comment: Never realized ps had a format-output flag. Thak you wRAR! I'm good with my script now! :)

Comment: +1 for recommending `ps`. Using `top` in a script means setting yourself up for headaches and bugs which are hard to track. From [`man top`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top): `-c` : *Command line/Program name **toggle** | Starts top with the **last remembered** 'c' state **reversed**. Thus, if top was displaying command lines, now that field will show program names, and visa versa.*